# Disparar evento ao clicar em dia no JCalendar?

Tags: java, swing, jcalendar

Como faço para colocar um evento em cada dia do JCalendar? Minha intenção é clicar em um dia e criar uma espécie de lembrete que fica relacionado com o dia, de um jeito que quando o usuário clica novamente no dia ele vê o lembrete, mas não faço ideia de como fazer com que cada dia do calendário funcione como um botão.

Answer (score 1):

Conforme [esta resposta no SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39051236/5524514), isso é possível adicionando um listener do tipo [`PropertyChangeListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html) ao JCalendar. Para isso, você precisa resgatar o componente responsável por listar os dias do mês, através do seu método `getDayChooser()`, e adicionar o listener a ele. Assim, cada vez que for clicado em algum dia, esse listener será disparado.

Veja um exemplo abaixo de como implementar:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import com.toedter.calendar.JCalendar;

public class JDateChooserActionDayTest extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JCalendar cal;
    private JPanel contentpane;

    public JDateChooserActionDayTest() {
        contentpane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JLabel label = new JLabel("");
        label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(contentpane.getWidth(), 20));
        label.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);;
        contentpane.add(label, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        cal = new JCalendar();
        cal.getDayChooser().addPropertyChangeListener("day", new PropertyChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
                label.setText("Clicou na data: "+ new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(cal.getDate()));
            }
        });

        contentpane.add(cal, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setContentPane(contentpane);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JDateChooserActionDayTest bg = new JDateChooserActionDayTest();
            bg.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            bg.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Funcionando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]